# HTML要素の textContent に `?.` 演算子で代入できない

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

#### 実現したいこと

TypeScriptで、HTML要素を取得して操作したい

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
代入式の左辺には、省略可能なプロパティ アクセスを指定できません。
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```js
const pref = document.getElementById("prefectures");
pref?.textContent = "hello world";
```

#### 試したこと

特になし

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

typescript:4.7.4
tsc:4.6.4
esnext

Comment: この質問はteratailにも投稿しています。https://teratail.com/questions/h43ptb09679fri ご回答どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `?.` の意図と問題

`pref` に付いている「`?.`」は[オプショナルチェーン](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)という演算子です。質問のコードでの意図は、

- [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) は `null` を返す可能性がある
- よって `pref` は `null` である可能性がある
- `null` のプロパティに通常の方法(`.` など)でアクセスしてしまうとエラー（例外）になる
- エラーを避けるため、`?.` を使おう

といった所だと思われます。しかし、これには問題があり、`?.` 演算子を代入式の代入される側（左辺）で使うことはできません。その理由は、`?.` 演算子が `undefined` を返すかも知れず、それにより `undefined` に代入することになっては困るからでしょう。

#### 対策: `pref` が `null` では無いことが確認された箇所で作業する

現象としては、TypsScript の型チェックが起り得るエラーを事前に発見してくれた、という事です。ですから対策としては、その起り得る状況(`pref` が `null` である)を実行時にチェックすることが考えられます。

`if` 内で `pref` を触る例:

```js
const pref = document.getElementById("prefectures")
// ここで `pref` の型は 「HTMLElement | null」
// つまり、`null` の可能性がある

if (pref !== null) {
    // このブロックでは `pref` は `null` で無いことが確認済み
    // 型は HTMLElement となっている
    pref.textContent = "hello world";
} else {
    // `null` であった場合の何らかの処理
    throw "ID `prefectures` を持つ要素が見付かりません"
}
```

例外を発生させ早期脱出する例:

```js
const pref = document.getElementById("prefectures")
// ここで `pref` の型は 「HTMLElement | null」
// つまり、`null` の可能性がある

if (pref === null) {
    throw "ID `prefectures` を持つ要素が見付かりません"
}
// これ以降に処理が進む場合は、`pref` が `null` で無いことが確認済みとなる
// 型は HTMLElement となっている

pref.textContent = "hello world"
```

こういった処理を「[型ガード](https://typescript-jp.gitbook.io/deep-dive/type-system/typeguard)」と呼ぶことがあります。